# 10 Trading.com - Fake or not?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, fraud

I invested small amount of money **5** years ago and then panicked and withdrew it all, 10Trading was the company and I believe they were closed down, however periodically I receive emails suggesting I still have an investment of bitcoin that needs refunding to me as 10Trading is shut, Is this just a very elaborate scam? or could I be owed money.. I don't understand bitcoin but the emails ask for various details and suggest it can be put into a Blockchain wallet or Kraken, which I have had help to set up but still suspicious of the emails should I block all contact?

Comment: It is a scam. If you withdrew your money five years ago, AND the company was closed down, then you don't have any money or cryptocurrency on deposit there. They are asking you for "various details" which means they are trying to phish information from you. Block all contact.

Comment: If it's real, they will just give you the money and maybe ask for ID (be cautious about giving them ID). If they demand money before they give you the money, then it's a scam. If they ask for your Blockchain Wallet password or Kraken password, it's a scam. If it's real, they only need your bitcoin address and they don't need to know anything else about your wallet.

Comment: @user253751 While we could construct contrived scenarios where it could happen, in actual practice I feel extremely confident in saying that if someone reaches out to you and claims to be in possession of bitcoin to which you have a claim, it is a scam 100% of the time.  You don't need to check anything.  it's *always* a scam.

Comment: @GrandOpener ... unless it was a trading platform where you bought some bitcoin and then the platform shut down

Answer (score 37):

There is a long history of somebody purchasing a dead trademark and url to make people believe that an old favorite is back.

This goes beyond that.

They have some information that tells them that you used to have an account. Their plan for you is to convince you to provide them with more information about you. This they can then use to get money from you directly, or they want to use the security and ID information you provide them to see if they can use that information in other places.

If you closed your account, and they went out of business, there is no reason to provide them with any more information. Ignore them. Block them.

Comment: Also if after reading this you're thinking "That all makes sense....but...what if I **do** have millions in bitcoin?"? This is what they're counting on.